# React Native - Random lines between list items

Tags: android, ios, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I have tried using a FlatList and a map function to generate a list of entries, but I am getting random lines between the entries (see the blue part of my screenshot)

What is causing these and how can I remove them?

Here is my FlatList:

```
<FlatList
    data={TriageTransfertData[0].content[0].content}
    renderItem={({ item }) => (
         <View style={styles.subentryContainer}>
           <View style={styles.ttEntryFirst} />
           <View style={styles.ttEntryContentSub}>
             <Text style={styles.ttTextSub}>{item.text}</Text>
           </View>
         </View>
     )}
     keyExtractor={item => item.text} />
```

And here is the styling:

```
subentryContainer: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    width: '100%',
},
ttEntryFirst: {
    width: '2%',
    backgroundColor: Colors.Blue
},
ttEntryContentSub: {
    width: '98%',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingLeft: responsiveWidth(2),
    paddingTop: 10,
    paddingBottom: 10,
    borderTopWidth: 1,
    borderColor: Colors.GreyLight
},
```

And finally, here is a screenshot (notice the unwanted line in the blue area):
[image: FlatList with unwanted line]

Answer (score 0):

I think you're talking about `ItemSeparatorComponent`. It's rendered by default in a FlatList, but you can override it passing a custom component or a blank code function.
Here is the brief [doc](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist#itemseparatorcomponent).

Hope this helps!